# Regex: Capture Everything between two words that does not have a specific string in the middle

Tags: regex

**Example Strings:**

> Dandelion The animal dog is blue
>
> The animal cat is blue
>
> Alcohol The animal cow is blue water

I need to use a regex that will capture all instances that starts with the word '**The**' and end with the word '**blue**', but doesn't have the word '**cat**' between these 2 words.

**What I tried:**

`The.*?(?!cat)blue`

**Desired Result:**

> 2 Matches:
>
> The animal dog is blue
>
> The animal cow is blue

Any help would be appreciated greatly

Comment: Are `The` and `blue` also allowed between `The` and `blue`?

Comment: `The(?:(?!cat).)+?blue`

Comment: The word `The` is allowed in between, the capture however should end at the first occurrence of the word `blue`

Comment: `the word` seems common to all your description. But, I don't think you know what the _`word`_ is in your context. `The cathouse has nice blue` paint, or `They concatenate over at blue` horizon, or `The cat is not blue`. So, which is it ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex - Get string between two words that doesn't contain word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333145/regex-get-string-between-two-words-that-doesnt-contain-word)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play with the character classes `\w`*(word characters)* and `\W` *(non-word characters)* and the word-boundary `\b` that matches between them. To forbid words, you only have to test them at a word-boundary using a negative lookahead `(?!...)` *(not followed by ...)*:

```
\bThe\W+(?:(?!cat\b|blue\b)\w+\W+)*blue\b
```

or with a perl compatible regex engine (that supports possessive quantifiers):

```
\bThe\W++(?:(?!cat\b|blue\b)\w+\W+)*+blue\b
```

This way, you are sure that `cat` isn't a part of `scat` or `catering`.

Answer (score 0):

".*" will match everything it can, so the "(?!cat)" portion will continue to match anything after ".*" has already matched "cat"

I would include the condition "not matching anything followed by cat" before matching "anything followed by blue" as follows:

```
The(?!.*cat).*blue
```

Comment: This will fail for "*The animal dog is blue, meow cat*"